# Need to print double as 12.20 instead of 12.2

Tags: c#

```
double s = 12.20;
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

It prints `12.2` but I need it to print `12.20`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the format for converting a number to a string - here's one way of many. Google ".net numeric format strings" for more...

```
Console.WriteLine(s.ToString("0.00"));
```

Answer (score 3):

quoting [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5.aspx)

`Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("F"));         // Displays -16325.00`

Answer (score 3):

try `s.ToString("0.00");`